# Proper way to receive a data structure with MPI_Gather

Tags: c, mpi

I have the following data structure which I'm trying to send with MPI_Gather:

```
struct set {
    int nbits;
    char  bits[];
};
```

Problem is that I'm unable to gather all items of the above structure, only the first item. The remaining items simply doesn't make sense.

Here is a testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mpi.h"

#define SIZE 10

struct set {
    int nbits;
    char bits[];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int np, rank, i;
    struct set *subsets, *single;
    void *buf;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    single = malloc(sizeof(struct set) + SIZE);

    if(rank == 0) {
            subsets = malloc((sizeof(struct set) + SIZE) * np);
    }

    buf = &subsets[0];

    MPI_Datatype set_type, oldtypes[2];
    int blockcounts[2];
    MPI_Aint offsets[2];
    MPI_Aint addr[3];

    MPI_Get_address(single, &addr[0]);
    MPI_Get_address(&single->nbits, &addr[1]);
    MPI_Get_address(&single->bits, &addr[2]);

    offsets[0] = addr[1] - addr[0];
    oldtypes[0] = MPI_INT;
    blockcounts[0] = 1;

    offsets[1] = addr[2] - addr[0];
    oldtypes[1] = MPI_CHAR;
    blockcounts[1] = SIZE;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &set_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&set_type);

    single->nbits = 2;

    for(i=0; i<single->nbits; i++)
            single->bits[i] = 'A' + rank;

    MPI_Gather(single, 1, set_type, buf, 1, set_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank == 0) {
            void *ptr;
            struct set *fs;
            int size;

            MPI_Type_size(set_type, &size);

            ptr = buf;

            for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
                    size_t j;

                    fs = ptr;
                    printf("from rank %d: bits => %p nbits => %d\n", i, fs->bits, fs->nbits);

                    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
                            printf("from rank %d: buf[%d] = %#x\n",
                                    i, j, fs->bits[j]);
                    ptr += size;
            }
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&set_type);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't so much in the `MPI` as in the pointer arithmetic with structs and with MPI types.

You have

```
        void *ptr;
        struct set *fs;
        int size;

        MPI_Type_size(set_type, &size);

        ptr = buf;

        for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
                size_t j;

                fs = ptr;
                printf("from rank %d: bits => %p nbits => %d\n", i, fs->bits, fs->nbits);

                for(j=0; j<2; j++)
                        printf("from rank %d: buf[%d] = %#x\n",
                                i, j, fs->bits[j]);
                ptr += size;
        }
}
```

But [`MPI_Type_size`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_size.html) actually gives the amount of data in the type; if there's padding (which there probably will be here to get the character array to be on a word boundary) this isn't the same as `sizeof`.   If you want to use MPI functions here, if you switch that one function call to [`MPI_Type_extent`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_extent.html), which actually tells you the entire extent spanned by the type, your code runs for me... but there's still a problem.

If you take a look at the difference between `sizeof(struct set)+SIZE` and `MPI_Type_extent()` you'll see they're not the same; this:

```
#define SIZE 10
struct set {
  int nbits
  char nbits[]
}

...

malloc(sizeof(struct set)+SIZE);
```

isn't the same as

```
struct set {
  int nbits
  char nbits[SIZE]
}

malloc(sizeof(struct set));
```

because of padding, etc.   This means that the size of `subsets` is wrong, and there's a memory error when you call `MPI_Gather`.

You can get around this in a few different ways, but the simplest (and shortest in terms of line count) is to define the structure with the array already sized, and then use array indexing instead of pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mpi.h"

#define SIZE 10

struct set {
    int nbits;
    char bits[SIZE];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int np, rank, i;
    struct set *subsets, *single;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    single = malloc(sizeof(struct set));

    if(rank == 0) {
            subsets = malloc(sizeof(struct set) * np);
    }

    MPI_Datatype set_type, oldtypes[2];
    int blockcounts[2];
    MPI_Aint offsets[2];
    MPI_Aint addr[3];

    MPI_Get_address(single, &addr[0]);
    MPI_Get_address(&single->nbits, &addr[1]);
    MPI_Get_address(&single->bits, &addr[2]);

    offsets[0] = addr[1] - addr[0];
    oldtypes[0] = MPI_INT;
    blockcounts[0] = 1;

    offsets[1] = addr[2] - addr[0];
    oldtypes[1] = MPI_CHAR;
    blockcounts[1] = SIZE;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &set_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&set_type);

    single->nbits = 2;

    for(i=0; i<single->nbits; i++)
            single->bits[i] = 'A' + rank;

    MPI_Gather(single, 1, set_type, &(subsets[0]), 1, set_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank == 0) {
            for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
                    struct set *fs = &(subsets[i]);
                    printf("from rank %d: bits => %p nbits => %d\n", i, fs->bits, fs->nbits);

                    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
                            printf("from rank %d: buf[%d] = %#x\n",
                                    i, j, fs->bits[j]);
            }
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&set_type);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**Updated to add** And if you can't do that, just change the size of your buffer alloc to gather the data into:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define SIZE 10

struct set {
    int nbits;
    char bits[];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int np, rank, i;
    struct set *single;
    void *buf;
    ptrdiff_t extent;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    single = malloc(sizeof(struct set) + SIZE);

    MPI_Datatype set_type, oldtypes[2];
    int blockcounts[2];
    MPI_Aint offsets[2];
    MPI_Aint addr[3];

    MPI_Get_address(single, &addr[0]);
    MPI_Get_address(&single->nbits, &addr[1]);
    MPI_Get_address(&single->bits, &addr[2]);

    offsets[0] = addr[1] - addr[0];
    oldtypes[0] = MPI_INT;
    blockcounts[0] = 1;

    offsets[1] = addr[2] - addr[0];
    oldtypes[1] = MPI_CHAR;
    blockcounts[1] = SIZE;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &set_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&set_type);

    MPI_Type_extent(set_type, &extent);
    buf = malloc((int)extent * np);

    single->nbits = 2;

    for(i=0; i<single->nbits; i++)
            single->bits[i] = 'A' + rank;

    MPI_Gather(single, 1, set_type, buf, 1, set_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank == 0) {
            struct set *fs = buf;
            for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
                    printf("from rank %d: bits => %p nbits => %d\n", i, fs->bits, fs->nbits);

                    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
                            printf("from rank %d: buf[%d] = %#x\n",
                                    i, j, fs->bits[j]);

                    fs = (struct set *)((char *)fs + extent);
            }
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&set_type);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need that struct to be a variable-length object, since I don't have the size of the character array beforehand (i.e. in the real scenario).

Comment: Fine, then use MPI_Type_extent to size the array malloc.

Comment: Now it works just as you've said about MPI_Type_get_extent and MPI_Type_size. The problem was that I was allocating / indexing my data structure upon MPI_Type_size / sizeof. Thanks ;)

Comment: @ShippDouglas: the edited line `fs += ((void *)fs + extent);` is wrong. There is no arithmetic possible on void pointers **PLUS**: even if there were such an operation,  the RHS evaluates to a pointer type, and `pointer += pointer` is impossible. (in standard C). The original with `ptr += size;` looked better.